# video streaming asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video, streaming, buffering

i've been making an asp website in which i'm providing the user a facility to upload videos and view them once they are uploaded. I've been successfully been able to upload videos to my server, but not getting as how to play it on the client's page. I want to buffer the video and stream it on user's browser, don't want him to wait and download the whole video before playing. How can i approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May want to try installing [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/serve/prodinfo2008.aspx) on your server and play around with it.

HowTo here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/webserver.aspx

API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738748.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use windows mediaplayer component. Here is an [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/CsharpWebVideo04212007133218PM/CsharpWebVideo.aspx) about that. Have you thought about using silverlight? Here is [one](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=217) for you using Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Video.Show](http://www.codeplex.com/videoshow).